# Use noindex for URL with parameters?

Tags: seo, google, noindex, url-parameters

I have a homepage, `https://example.com`, where a parameter can be added to unlock a discount on our website `https://example.com?code=abc`. I don't want this URL to be appear in Google search results, which it currently does.

According to the following doc, I should add a noindex meta tag:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846#make_permanent

I am wondering though if I really should add a noindex meta tag to my homepage when the code parameter is present. I obviously don't want to hurt my home pages' SEO. Specifically, I have some link juice for `https://example.com?code=abc` and would like that to benefit `https://example.com`.

Question 1: is this really safe?

Question 2: would a canonical tag serve the same purpose? So that `https://example.com?code=abc` declares `https://example.com` as canonical. To make things more complicated, the homepage is actually localized as `https://example.com/de?code=abc` and `https://example.com/en?code=abc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely want to use a canonical tag here, not `noindex`.

For URLs of the form `https://example.com/de?code=abc`, use a canonical tag pointing to `https://example.com/de`.

For URLs of the form `https://example.com/en?code=abc`, use a canonical tag pointing to `https://example.com/en`.

The `noindex` directive tells the crawler that it should not index the page. The `canonical` tag tells the crawler that it should index the page but at a different URL, which fits your intent much more closely.

Comment: Hm, I thought so too in theory, but I've done that many days ago and Google Search results still lists `https://example.com/de?code=abc`... (I've already asked to recrawl the page etc)

Comment: This is precisely what my head includes: <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/en"><link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/en"><link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de">

Comment: Unfortunately, Google can take weeks to update its index depending on how often it crawls your site. If you've already requested a crawl, the only other thing to do may be to wait. Personally I would be wary of trying to speed it up through some sort of removal request. Google [says this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846?hl=en) about removal requests for non-canonical pages: *"Don’t use the URL tool to block the URLs you don’t want in search results. It won't keep your favorite version of a page; instead, could remove all versions (http/https and www/non-www) of a URL."*

Comment: Alright, it's not like it's a super prominent Search Result anyway, so I'll just leave it as is and check in on it every now and then. Thanks!

Comment: Can we get an update @TonaldDrump?  Did Google eventually update to your desired results using the canonical?

Comment: Yh, it's actually disappeared :)